# Disable all shared folder

Tags: windows, windows-xp

What is the CMD Command to Disable the All share folder on the Win XP machines.

Thank You

Answer (score 10):

Deliver command in this sequence

```
net share
```

This will enlist all the shared resources

```
net share DataShare /delete
```

where datashare is the choice you want to remove

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490712.aspx

Answer (score 5):

(For Win10)

1- Run cmd.exe as administrator

2- `wmic path Win32_Share delete`

Comment: This command disable share feature too, how can i share again !? how to reverse it ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the next steps:

1. Click Start, then right-click Computer, and then click Manage.
2. In the console tree, click System Tools, then click Shared Folders, and then click Shares.
3. In the details pane, right-click a shared folder, and then click Stop Sharing (this item only appears if you launched Computer Management using an account that is a member of the local Administrators group).
4. To stop sharing multiple files, press the CTRL key while clicking the file names, right-click any one of the selected files, and then click Stop Sharing. This removes shared network access to the selected files.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753475(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
wmic path Win32_Share delete
```

(tested on win10)

Comment: Worked on win 7

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the cmd command and if you want to automate it.
But if it's a 1 time thing you need to do you can always run mmc.exe and add the Shared Folders snapin via File/Add Remove snap-in.

In this screen you will get a list of all your shares and you can disable them as needed.